# How can I convert the following Django view to return JSON with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, rest, view

I am returning a bunch of tuples with the following code. The returned values involves data from a number of different models. I was wondering how to serialize the data and eventually return it in JSON format.

```
def Stream(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(hearts__gte=1)
    combined = sorted(chain(questions, answers), key=attrgetter('created'), reverse=True)
    queryset = []
    for item in combined:
        if hasattr(item, 'parent'):
            try:
                qs_heart = AnswerHeart.objects.get(answer=item, user=request.user)
                if qs_heart:
                    hearted = True
            except AnswerHeart.DoesNotExist:
                hearted = False
            try:
                qs_flag = AnswerFlag.objects.get(answer=item, user=request.user)
                if qs_flag:
                    flagged = True
            except AnswerFlag.DoesNotExist:
                flagged = False
            queryset.append((item, hearted, flagged))
        else:
            try:
                qs_heart = QuestionHeart.objects.get(question=item, user=request.user)
                if qs_heart:
                    hearted = True
            except QuestionHeart.DoesNotExist:
                hearted = False
            try:
                qs_flag = QuestionFlag.objects.get(question=item, user=request.user)
                if qs_flag:
                    flagged = True
            except QuestionFlag.DoesNotExist:
                flagged = False
            queryset.append((item, hearted, flagged))
    comments = QuestionComment.objects.all()
    return render(request, "alpha/stream.html", {'queryset': queryset, 'comments': comments})
```

Comment: Till now I have always used `generics` for a particular model and that has worked well. I haven't tried anything on this code so far as I don't know where or how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do something like this?

```
class MyThingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_thing_email = serializers.EmailField()

def my_view(request):
    serializer = MyThingSerializer(my_things, many=True)

    return HttpResponse(JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data), content_type='application/json')
```